# How to change the text of a button clicked in another class? (Python - tkinter)

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, button, tkinter

**Introduction**

I'm trying to create a GUI application with tkinter in python that has 2 frames that relate to each other. The general idea is to create a character selection menu (as in games). Everything was going well until it reached the part of changing the text of the buttons that are in different classes.

**Goals**

- The first frame, represented by **class A**, will be the main page of the application and should display 10 buttons on the screen;
- The second frame, represented by **class B**, will only be displayed to the user when any button in class A is clicked;
- Class B should display a list of buttons. When any of the Class B buttons are clicked, the text of this button that was clicked must be passed to the text of the Class A button.

**Details of the Project**

- This application should work as if it were a game character selection menu. Imagining this way, we commonly see this type of interaction between frames;
- There is a screen that shows the number of possible players for each game (In the case of this application, the buttons of class A will represent this) and there is a screen that shows all the characters available to be chosen (Buttons of class B);
- In the class A frame, there will be the player options: "Player 1, Player 2, Player 3 ...". So when clicking on one of these buttons (Player 1, Player 2, Player 3 ...) the window showing all the characters should be displayed (class B);
- When selecting the desired character (by clicking on one of the class B buttons), the chosen character must be passed to the main screen and shown on the button selected in class A. As I am not using images yet, I want to represent the characters by the text of the buttons;
- So if I click on the "Player 1" option on the main screen, and then select "Character 4" on the selection screen, the text for "Player 1" should be changed to "Character 4" on the main screen, and so on;

**Generic Code**

I made a generic representation of how I am building the program and detailing how I wanted it to work.

```
import tkinter as tk


# Creates the main window
class A(tk.Frame):
    """The class A frame is the main page of the application,
     when running the program, it will be the first thing shown to the user."""
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.bt_identities_a = []  # this list will be used to save the identities of each button created in class A

        # Creates multiple buttons
        for i in range(10):
            self.bt_a = tk.Button(self, text=f"Player  A{i}", command=lambda x=i: self.open_window_of_class_b(x))
            self.bt_a.grid()

            self.bt_identities_a.append(self.bt_a)  # adds the button identity to the list

    def open_window_of_class_b(self, n):
        """This is the method responsible for executing class B
            and for recognizing which button was clicked in class A

           All actions to be performed by the buttons in class B
            from now on must be associated with exactly that one
            button that was clicked in class A.
        """
        # Run class B
        B()

        # get the button id that was clicked
        bt_id = self.bt_identities_a[n]
        ...


# Creates the secondary window
class B(tk.Toplevel):
    """The class B frame is a secondary page that will only be opened if one of the Class A buttons is clicked."""
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.bt_identities_b = []  # this list will be used to save the identities of each button created in class B

        # Creates multiple buttons
        for j in range(10):
            self.bt_b = tk.Button(self, text=f"Character B{j}",
                                  command=lambda x=j: self.changes_the_text_of_a_button_in_class_a(x))
            self.bt_b.grid()

            self.bt_identities_b.append(self.bt_b)  # adds the button identity to the list

    def changes_the_text_of_a_button_in_class_a(self, n):
        """This method should recognize which of the Class B buttons that was clicked,
           take the text from this exact button and pass the text to the Class A button
           that was clicked just before."""

        # get the button id that was clicked
        bt_id = self.bt_identities_b[n]
        ...


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

app = A(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
app.mainloop()
```

**My real code**

And here is the complete code I have made so far from my application in case it is needed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import product


# Creating main page
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        # produce the set of coordinates of the main page buttons
        self.row_amount = 2
        self.column_amount = 5
        self.main_positions = product(range(self.row_amount), range(self.column_amount))
        self.main_buttons_identities = []

        # Creating main page header
        self.lb = tk.Label(self, width=111, height=4, bg="#2c3e50", text="Champions", fg="white", font=50,
                           justify=tk.CENTER)
        self.lb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 50), sticky="snew")

        # Creating Done button
        self.button = tk.Button(self, width=30, height=3, bg="#2c3e50", relief=tk.RIDGE, text="Done",
                                fg="white", font=20, command=root.destroy)
        self.button.grid(row=3, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 150))

        # Creating multiple buttons
        for i, item in enumerate(self.main_positions):
            self.button_main = tk.Button(self, width=16, height=8, bg="#2c3e50", relief=tk.RIDGE, fg="white",
                                         justify=tk.CENTER, text=f"Champion {i +1}",
                                         command=lambda c=i: [ChampionWindow(), self.clicked_main(c)])
            self.button_main.grid(row=item[0] + 1, column=item[1], pady=(0, 50))

            self.main_buttons_identities.append(self.button_main)

    def clicked_main(self, current_index):
        current = self.main_buttons_identities[current_index]

        print(current["text"])


# Creating champion select window
class ChampionWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # produce the set of coordinates of the char selection page buttons
        self.row_amount = 30
        self.column_amount = 5
        self.champion_position = product(range(self.row_amount), range(self.column_amount))
        self.champions_buttons_identities = []

        # scroll bar
        self.ch_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="blue", width=470, height=500)
        self.ch_frame = tk.Frame(self.ch_canvas, bg="#273c75")

        self.vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.ch_canvas.yview)

        self.ch_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set)
        self.ch_canvas.grid(sticky="snew")

        self.vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="sn")

        self.ch_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.ch_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.ch_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.scroll)

        # Creating multiple buttons
        for i, itm in enumerate(self.champion_position):
            self.button_champion = tk.Button(self.ch_frame, width=12, height=6, bg="#2c3e50",
                                             relief=tk.RIDGE, fg="white", justify=tk.CENTER,
                                             command=lambda c=i: [self.clicked_champion(c), self.destroy()],
                                             text=f"Pick champ {i+1}")
            self.button_champion.grid(row=itm[0], column=itm[1])

            self.champions_buttons_identities.append(self.button_champion)

    def scroll(self, ch_event):
        self.ch_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.ch_canvas.bbox("all"))

    def clicked_champion(self, champ_index):
        champ = self.champions_buttons_identities[champ_index]
        print(champ["text"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Champion")
    root.geometry("1000x570+450+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    app = MainApplication(root)
    app.configure(background="#34495e")
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

**GUI images**

To make it easier to understand what I'm trying to do, I'll link the images from the main window and the character selection window.

[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umk7e.png) (Displays the players)

[Character Selection Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uru5q.png) (Displays available characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the instance of clicked button to `ChampionWindow` class:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):

        ...

        # Creating multiple buttons
        for i, item in enumerate(self.main_positions):
            button_main = tk.Button(self, width=16, height=8, bg="#2c3e50", relief=tk.RIDGE, fg="white",
                                    justify=tk.CENTER, text=f"Champion {i +1}",
                                    command=lambda c=i: self.clicked_main(c))
            button_main.grid(row=item[0] + 1, column=item[1], pady=(0, 50))
            self.main_buttons_identities.append(button_main)

    def clicked_main(self, current_index):
        current = self.main_buttons_identities[current_index]
        print(current["text"])
        ChampionWindow(current) # pass clicked button to ChampionWindow
```

Then update the text of the passed button in `ChampionWindow` when one of its buttons is clicked:

```
# Creating champion select window
class ChampionWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, button, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = button   # save the button for later use

        ...    

    def clicked_champion(self, champ_index):
        champ = self.champions_buttons_identities[champ_index]
        print(champ["text"])
        self.button["text"] = champ["text"]  # update passed button
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. You can apply changes to class variables externally once the class has been initialized.

Here is a simple example.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.champ = None

    def get_name(self):
        B()
    def test(self):
        print(self.champ)
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Assingin name")
        f.champ = "Hero1"
        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = A()
    f.test()
    f.get_name()
    f.test()
```

In your scenario, you would change app.whatever as your main program is globally initialized as app. So simply creating a list to fill or independent variables or dicts can then be passed by assigning values to them from the secondary class.

I believe extending to fit your exact use case is quite possible and I can provide a much more robust solution at a later time.

Comment: Would it be better if I don't initialize the program globally?

Comment: No. I am not a leading expert but I believe what you are doing is considered best practice to initialize your program under if__name__ block.